# TypeScript: Substitute Namespaces with something else

Tags: typescript, tslint, javascript-namespaces

TSLint complains that namespaces shouldn't be used and as far as I understand the common sense is that they shouldn't be used anymore as they are special TypeScript construct.

So, I have a simple Timestamp interface:

```
export interface Timestamp {
  seconds: number | Long;
  nanos: number;
}
```

Due to the lack of static functions in interfaces, I use namespaces to organize that functionality, like this:

```
export namespace Timestamp {
  export function now(): Timestamp {
    ...
  }
}
```

How would you model that now without a namespace? The following construct looks ugly, is there another way?

```
export const Timestamp = {
  now: () => {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, I checked lib.es6.d.ts and it looks like a "const object" is really the way to go:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    ...
    now(): number;
    ...
}

declare const Date: DateConstructor;
```

Interestingly, the following construct also works and I would consider that as the "clean" approach:

```
export interface Timestamp {
  seconds: number | Long;
  nanos: number;
}

export class Timestamp {
  public static now(): Timestamp {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: For a more informed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415859/should-i-prefer-namespaces-or-classes-with-static-functions